# hibernate insert ignore in same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates

I'm working with JPA2 and Hibernate 3, using MySQL for a database. There is class a `TestB` as follows:

```
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO testB (....) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ;")
class TestB{
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @ID
  private long id;

  @Column(unique)
  String ccc; 
}
```

For the transaction start:

```
@Transactional

List<TestB> list = ...
repoitory.save(list);
```

But unfortunately, this is a bulk insert, so I cannot save all of the data in memory. What I chose to do is, just pass the data to the database, and the database decides what to do.

For pure SQL, `INSERT IGNORE` works just fine. But for Hibernate, I tried two things.

```
1. Insert Ignore
2. Insert .. on duplicate update (...)
```

Neither work. The errors for each are,

```
1. The database returned no natively generated identity value.
2. NonUniqueObject Exception.
```

Both happen for the duplicate entry, not the first one.

I assume that the first error occurred because after insert, Hibernate should assign an ID to the proxy object, but it can't. I assume the second error occurred because two objects with same ID cannot existed in the same session.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, hibernate tries to insert data into the table if there is no constraint violations or sql errors. If there are any exceptions (say unique key violations.. ) since you have used INSERT IGNORE DB doesn't insert anything into the DB, so there is no ID which is generated natively; Hibernate throws a system Exception with the error `The database returned no natively generated identity value`.

One of the Solutions: Well one way of handling this error is to catch HibernateSystemException, which is thrown when insert fails and is ignored by MySQL DB.

Since this is an hibernate system exception, Hibernate internally seems to mark the transaction for rollback even if one of the ignore fails. I am trying to find a solution to this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was trying to do what you suggested, but I have no idea how to catch hibernate system Exception.. thanks anyway~

Comment: The problem with catching hibernate system exception in the @transactional context is that hibernate marks the transaction as rollback. So even if you handle the HibernateSystemException by surrounding the DB operation with try catch block.

Comment: Work around for this would be to use JDBC template and JDBC simple insert or just build a JDBC insert statement and execute.